# How to make Selenium looks for multiple objects?

Tags: python, selenium

I want to make the program checks for page_1 and page_2 all the time until they find it and then I can execute other stuff like `send.keys` or `driver.navigate().refresh();` But I only got my code working if only one variable is provided, when there are 2 or more variables that do the `wait.until` it will not do anything.

```
class element_has_css_class(object):
  """An expectation for checking that an element has a particular css class.

  locator - used to find the element
  returns the WebElement once it has the particular css class
  """
  def __init__(self, locator, css_class):
    self.locator = locator
    self.css_class = css_class

  def __call__(self, driver):
    element = driver.find_element(*self.locator)   # Finding the referenced element
    if self.css_class in element.get_attribute("class"):
        return element
    else:
        return False
# Wait
wait = WebDriverWait(driver, 1000)
# Variables
page_1 = wait.until(element_has_css_class((By.ID, 'loginactioncontainer'), "w3-right")) #w3schools.com
page_2 = wait.until(element_has_css_class((By.ID, 'gh-gb'), "gh-sch-prom")) #ebay.com
#
if page_1.is_displayed():
    print("Nice!")
else:
    print("not Found!")

if page_2.is_displayed():
    print("Nice2!")
else:
    print("not Found2!")
```

What would be the best way to do this?

Comment: Why dont you get the current URL? If you're doing what I think that too overcomplicated. Just get the URL and check if eBay in the URL.

Comment: The websites were examples I actually need to do it without the links.

Comment: get the head title tag maybe? And check through that?

Comment: Can't do like that too, as in the website I will use this, only change the code itself but not the title or link

Comment: So you want to detect a website with out needing of a statement?

Comment: What do you mean?

Comment: Can you explain what you want to do?

Comment: I want to make a loop that will check for find_elements_by_id etc.. from a list of other elements, all of the elements will be stored in a variable (as in my example) for easy access. The program looks for the varibale all the time and when it  detects a elements for example `page_6 = driver.find_element_by_id('loginForm')` the it would do this for example `page_6.click()` whenever it's on page_6, I hope you understand

Comment: I want to make a simple bot that will navigate a page and type some stuff and click some buttons

Comment: Then why dont you figure out which URL it is and then do an action? You can use try-except but that will be slow and resource intensive

Comment: The thing is the URL just doesn't change. What would be better than try-except?

Comment: ebay.com and w3schools.com are pretty different so I dont know where it doesn't change. Maybe making functions for each task and running them accordingly?

Comment: They were an example as I actually can't give the website's link because it's password protected and you couldn't see the URL. Perhaps you can tell me how to make a never-ending python loop that would be efficient and would give out an output signal the moment it finds an element in the loop and then from there I could run code based on the signal the loop just gave me out.

Comment: will make an answer

Comment: Check my answer to see if that works.

Answer (score 0):

To make what you want you should do a loop and use try-except. Its not efficient but should work.

```
try:page_1 = wait.until(element_has_css_class((By.ID, 'loginactioncontainer'), "w3-right")) #w3schools.com
except: page_1 = False
try:page_2 = wait.until(element_has_css_class((By.ID, 'gh-gb'), "gh-sch-prom")) #ebay.com
except: page_2 = False
#
if page_1:
    print("Nice!")
else:
    print("not Found!")

if page_2:
    print("Nice2!")
else:
    print("not Found2!")
```

Comment: It doesn't work for me. I need it so it checks for page_1 and page_2 and when I land on one of the pages, it will just print out Nice! or Nice2! and continue to look for other pages, is that possible?

Comment: I think I found a way to do it. https://polling2.readthedocs.io/en/latest/index.html This could help me right?